# permission exception on Lollipop only and pre-Lollipop NOT

Tags: android, android-permissions

Anyone have worked with `RingToneManager`?

I have this method which get the ringtones names and their uri available on mobile device

http://pastebin.com/KGTw3kab

it works on pre-Lollipop devices (KitKat) well and everything is perfect 
but when I run it on Lollipop device it gives this exception

> "requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

-please don't tell me to add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission because it's added and the app works on pre-Lollipop devices only and that's the problem.

Comment: "because its added" -- please post your manifest, along with the entire stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: here's the manifest http://pastebin.com/WmZthkP8 the program works perfectly on kitkat but on lolipop its says requires read...etc permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Android is case-sensitive in most places. Please change this to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

With respect to the change in behavior on Android 5.0, they now require you to be able to read external storage to access stuff from `MediaStore` that resides on external storage. This is not unique to ringtones.